# What are the equivalence classes of this relation?

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

Let $f \colon X → X$ be an injective function.

For $y, z ∈ X$, define $y \sim z$ to mean there
exists an integer $n ≥ 0$ such that either $f^n(z) = y$ or $f^n(y) = z$. (Here $f^0(z) = z$ for all $z ∈ X$.)

Prove this is defines an equivalence relation on $X$.

Give a list of the different possibilities for the
resulting equivalence classes

My attempt: Proving it was an equivalence relation was simple as it involved only using definitions of the function, but I have no idea what the equivalence classes must be.

Comment: My guess is that you're being asked to describe the "shape" of the possible equivalence classes.

Comment: I do not know how to even begin thinking about that, which is my main issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is asking for **various possibilities** for the equivalence classes. So

1). If $x \in X$ is a fixed point of the function i.e. $f(x)=x$, then $[x]=\{x\}$. Due to injectivity, no other element will map to $x$, so it is the only member in it’s class.

2). If there exists a finite sequence $x_1, x_2, \ldots ,x_k$, such that $f(x_i)=x_{i+1}$ and $f(x_k)=x_1$. Then $[x_1]=\{x_1, x_2, \ldots ,x_k \}$.

3). Other possibility is to have infinite orbits.

Comment: The "infinite orbit" case might also split into the case $\{ \ldots, x_{-2}, x_{-1}, x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots \}$ where $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, or the case $\{ x_0, x_1, x_2, \ldots \}$ where $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ but $x_0$ is not in the image of $f$.

Comment: I understand 1 and 2, but could you please explain what you mean by infinite orbits?

Comment: @childishsadbino Here is an example that can help. Consider $f(x_{i})=x_{i+2}$. Then $f(x_1)=x_3, f(x_3)=x_5, \ldots$ and $f(x_2)=x_4, f(x_4)=x_6, \ldots$. Thus $[x_1]=\{x_1,x_3,x_5, \ldots\}$ and $[x_2]=\{x_2,x_4,x_6, \ldots\}$. So they are infinite orbits.

Comment: Are these the only possibilities?